# Take action if a value isn't in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working in jQuery Vector Map user selected region names I have to added in div tag. 
I done that part.

But user should not added the same region more than one time (if already added region).
So I stored all regions name in array.

For example when I click Arizona region - in console it showing 3 time "false " and 1 time "true". The arizona region value getting added in div 3 times.

If I click again same region it get adding 3 times once again.

```
var regionList = new Array('Alaska','Alabama','Arkansas','Arizona') /* sample array*/

for(i=0;i<regionList.length;i++)
{
    if(region == regionList[i])
    {
      console.log(true);
      alert("Region already assigned");
    }
    else
    {   
      console.log(false);
      $('<li>' + region + '</li>').appendTo('ul#location-selected');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write it totally different but keeping your way:

```
var regionList = new Array('Alaska','Alabama','Arkansas','Arizona') /* sample array*/
//  region isn't in region list.
if($.inArray(region,regionList) == -1)
{
    console.log(true);
    alert("Region already assigned");
}
//  region is in region list.
else
{   console.log(false);
    $('<li>' + region + '</li>').appendTo('ul#location-selected');
}
```

[inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is Arizona will match once but fail the other three times so the else is executed three times and if only once. try this:

```
var flag=0;
var regionList = new Array('Alaska','Alabama','Arkansas','Arizona') /* sample array*/
                for(i=0;i<regionList.length;i++)
                {
                    if(region == regionList[i])
                    {
                        console.log(true);
                        alert("Region already assigned");
                        flag=1;
                    }
                }
if(flag==0)
{   console.log(false);
                        $('<li>' + region + '</li>').appendTo('ul#location-selected');
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic of whether to add the region to a list should be outside of the loop. While in the loop you're simply finding out whether this region doesn't already exist.
Here's an example, but I would also use `inArray` jQuery function as per @gdoron 's answer.

```
var regionList = new Array('Alaska','Alabama','Arkansas','Arizona')
var isNewRegion = true;
for(i=0;i<regionList.length;i++)
{
    if(region == regionList[i])
    {
        isNewRegion = false;
        console.log(true);
        alert("Region already assigned");
     }
}

if (isNewRegion )
{   
    console.log(false);
    $('<li>' + region + '</li>').appendTo('ul#location-selected');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by using js object too:

```
var regionList = {'Alaska': true,'Alabama': true,'Arkansas': true,'Arizona': true};
if(regionList[region])
{
    alert("Region already assigned");
}
else
{   
    regionList[region] = true;
    $('<li>' + region + '</li>').appendTo('ul#location-selected');
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible with objects, but it doesn't make sense, why would you add to every value a redundant `true`?  won't downvote, but it is a very bad design IMO.

Comment: i believe it wont make any difference if you have to store here few regions. It is pure JS check anyway and you don`t bother with any compatibility issues like indexOf in IE.

Comment: as I wrote, it won't make anything to crash or will slow the browser, it's only a poor design(making an array an object so you can use the `[]` operator, there are other,better ways to determine  if a value exists or not in arrays)

Comment: Thanks for all above reply but Its not meeting my expectation..  I want to add selected region if its not already there . Same time I should add the same region once again.. let me help me... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need the for loop as long as region is only one string, i.e. 'Arizona' or 'failString'

```
var regionList = ['Alaska', 'Alabama', 'Arkansas', 'Arizona']
if (regionList.indexOf(region) != -1) {
    // If region exists in the array
    console.log('true');
} else {
    // If region doesn't exist in the array
    console.log('false');
}
```